# How do you rename a MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, database

There's a typo in my MongoDB database name and I'm looking to rename the database.

I can [copy](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Copy+Database+Commands) and delete like so...

```
db.copyDatabase('old_name', 'new_name');
use old_name
db.dropDatabase();
```

Is there a command to rename a database?

Comment: from **mongo 4.2** even `copyDatabase` is also [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#remove-support-for-the-copydb-and-clone-commands)

Answer (score 237, accepted):

No there isn't. See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-701

> Unfortunately, this is not an simple feature for us to implement due to the way that database metadata is stored in the original (default) storage engine. In MMAPv1 files, the namespace (e.g.: dbName.collection) that describes every single collection and index includes the database name, so to rename a set of database files, every single namespace string would have to be rewritten. This impacts:
>
> - the .ns file
> - every single numbered file for the collection
> - the namespace for every index
> - internal unique names of each collection and index
> - contents of system.namespaces and system.indexes (or their equivalents in the future)
> - other locations I may be missing
>
> This is just to accomplish a rename of a single database in a **standalone** mongod instance. For replica sets the above would need to be done on every replica node, plus on each node every single oplog entry that refers this database would have to be somehow invalidated or rewritten, and then if it's a sharded cluster, one also needs to add these changes to every shard if the DB is sharded, plus the config servers have all the shard metadata in terms of namespaces with their full names.
>
> There would be absolutely no way to do this on a live system.
>
> To do it offline, it would require re-writing every single database file to accommodate the new name, and at that point it would be as slow as the current "copydb" command...

Comment: That ticket has been open for a very long time. I've added my less-than-important vote to the already long list.

Comment: The way they have built the DB and explained it, renaming seems impossible - might take a whole new architecture. Seems like a big oversight but all is fair in love, war and software development.

Comment: So MongoDB should have one command that calls two functions, copy and drop? I don't see a big reason to have this single command. But it could be nice to some.

Comment: When you name the database to begin with, that SHOULD just be an alias for an internal-name that Mongo generates (using a globally unique naming convention). This way, changing a database's name is as simple as changing that alias and propagating it to all nodes in the cluster. I say SHOULD. This is not the case.

Comment: that's outrageous

Comment: @Bernardo Del Corno Totally agree. MongoDB is like an shiny and attractive looking car. But when you get inside the drivers seat you realize that everything is a little bit wonky. You can indicate right but not left. Pressing the accelator pedal turns the volume up on the stereo. Winding the window down results in the engine overheating and the car stopping until it cools down. And every time you think you have this car figured out, another curveball comes flying through the windscreen. Source: 7 years of working with MongoDB, much of it professionally.

Answer (score 442):

You could do this, if you're using MongoDB < 4.2 ([ref](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/)):

```
db.copyDatabase("db_to_rename","db_renamed","localhost")
use db_to_rename
db.dropDatabase();
```

Editorial Note: this is the same approach used in the question itself but has proven useful to others regardless.

Comment: The answer is confusing with regards to the 3rd argument of `copyDatabase`. See the [MongoDB Copy Database Commands](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Copy+Database+Commands) to get clear.

Comment: For the 3rd argument I suggest putting "localhost". Edited for clarity

Comment: The 3rd argument can actually be omitted, and it will default to the same server.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work when db_to_rename and db_renamed only differ in case. You have to use a temporary database in that situation. (I just ran into this :)

Comment: How is this different from the solution provided by the OP?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286873/machine-hangs-when-mongodb-db-copydatabase-takes-all-vailable-ram db.copyDatabase() does an in-memory copy. Is that true?

Comment: please note, the third parameter "localhost" is optional.

Comment: this is same as the actual Question with the only difference being the third argument in `copyDatabase` method

Comment: this is same as the actual Question with the only difference being the third argument in `copyDatabase` method*, which is unnecessary, and therefore a worse solution that one that the OP was already aware of.* cc @GurbakhshishSingh

Comment: WARNING: It is absolutely slow, includes full database scan and index rebuild. YOU CAN NOT KILL THE OPERATION WHEN YOU INITIATED IT. So, your disk space may be killed, slowness, etc.

Comment: I was using the `robomongo` client and I did a `use db` before performing `db.dropDatabase()` and accidently dropped a different db. It makes sense to update the answer to add some more steps to verify you are on the right db or at least add a comment that dropped db is not reversible.

Comment: Beyond it almost being a copy-paste of the sample from the original question, it's also invalid and non-functional after 4.0, as they've removed `copyDatabase` entirely.  Ref. [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57811701/211827) for the current, modern approach.

Comment: WARNING: db.copyDatabase will only function with MongoDB 4.0 and below. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.2-copydb-clone

Comment: `db.copyDatabase` is no longer on mongodb 4.4

Comment: copyDatabase() is deprecated and won't work any more.

Answer (score 333):

Alternative solution: you can dump your db and restore that in different name. As I've experienced it's much quicker than `db.copyDatabase()`.

```
$ mongodump -d old_db_name -o mongodump/
$ mongorestore -d new_db_name mongodump/old_db_name
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-mongodump/

---

This is the current official [recommended approach](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-701) for database renames, given that `copyDatabase` [was removed](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#remove-support-for-the-copydb-and-clone-commands) in MongoDB 4.2:

> The "copydb" command is deprecated, please use these two commands instead:
>
> 1. [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) (to back up data)
> 2. [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) (to recover data from mongodump into a new namespace)

Comment: This is faster and as a "side effect", your database is compacted as well.

Comment: This is great! I already had a `mongodump` created. Didnt know you can restore it with a different name. Thanks!

Comment: NOTE: This doesn't work if you use `--gzip` and create an archive

Comment: This is the recommended way now, since `db.copyDatabase()` is now deprecated

Comment: Noting that no, the `--db` (`-d`) argument is itself also deprecated.  There's been a bit of a deprecation party going on, it seems, given [`copyDatabase` is also gone.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-compatibility/#copydb-and-clone-commands)  I've poked [SERVER-701 with my notes](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-701?focusedCommentId=2409300&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-2409300).

Comment: As of September 10, 2019, this is the recommended approach in Mongo issue [\[Server-701\]](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-701) requesting the database rename feature.

Comment: Thanks @tomako for your answer. This is the only solution that worked for me. The official solution for `mongodump` and `mongorestore` as mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/?&_ga=2.126971021.1469458796.1649914316-1657763159.1648793391#copy-clone-a-database) never worked on my Windows 10 PC. Though the `mongodump` succeeded, the `mongorestore` failed every time throwing `duplicate key error` despite being tried to restore to a new database. I don't know why and how did it get the `duplicate key error`. Finally, this solution saved my day.

Comment: This doesn't work now:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67656468/mongorestore-0-documents-restored-successfully-0-documents-failed-to-restor

Comment: just to add a note: 
`copyDatabase()` was removed because it was deprecated in MongoDB 4.0

Answer (score 31):

> NOTE: Hopefully this changed in the latest version.
>
> You cannot copy data between a MongoDB 4.0 mongod instance (regardless
>   of the FCV value) and a MongoDB 3.4 and earlier mongod instance.
>   https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/

**ALERT**: Hey folks just be careful while copying the database, if you don't want to mess up the different collections under single database.

**The following shows you how to rename**

```
> show dbs;
testing
games
movies
```

To rename you use the following syntax

```
db.copyDatabase("old db name","new db name")
```

Example:

```
db.copyDatabase('testing','newTesting')
```

Now you can safely delete the old db by the following way

```
use testing;

db.dropDatabase(); //Here the db **testing** is deleted successfully
```

**Now just think what happens if you try renaming the new database name with existing database name**

Example:

```
db.copyDatabase('testing','movies');
```

So in this context all the collections (tables) of **testing** will be copied to **movies** database.

Comment: [`copyDatabase` is gone.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-compatibility/#copydb-and-clone-commands)  I've poked [SERVER-701 with my notes](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-701?focusedCommentId=2409300&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-2409300).

Comment: @amcgregor thanks for notifying. I have added a comment for the same. Hope it helps some one.

Comment: `db.copyDatabase` is no longer on mongodb 4.4

Comment: @datinhquoc yup added that as comment

Answer (score 31):

From version 4.2, the `copyDatabase` is deprecated. From now on we should use: `mongodump` and `mongorestore`.

Let's say we have a database named: `old_name` and we want to rename it to `new_name`.

First we have to dump the database:

```
mongodump --archive="old_name_dump.db" --db=old_name
```

If you have to authenticate as a user then use:

```
mongodump -u username --authenticationDatabase admin \
          --archive="old_name_dump.db" --db=old_name
```

Now we have our db dumped as a file named: `old_name_dump.db`.

To restore with a new name:

```
mongorestore --archive="old_name_dump.db" --nsFrom="old_name.*" --nsTo="new_name.*"
```

Again, if you need to be authenticated add this parameters to the command:

```
-u username --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#remove-support-for-the-copydb-and-clone-commands

Comment: Instead of using an archive file, you can do the rename using the standard output as pipeline `mongodump --archive --db=old_name | mongorestore --archive  --nsFrom='old_name.*' --nsTo='new_name.*'`

Comment: Since mongo has deprecated all of the approaches in the other answers, this is now the only valid answer.

Answer (score 21):

Although Mongodb does not provide the rename Database command, it provides the r[ename Collection command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/), which not only modifies the collection name, but also modifies the database name.

```
{ renameCollection: "<source_namespace>", to: "<target_namespace>", dropTarget: <true|false>,  writeConcern: <document> }
```

```
db.adminCommand({renameCollection: "db1.test1", to: "db2.test2"})
```

This command only modifies the metadata, the cost is very small, we only need to traverse all the collections under `db1`, renamed to `db2` to achieve rename Database name.
you can do it  in this Js script

```
var source = "source";
var dest = "dest";
var colls = db.getSiblingDB(source).getCollectionNames();
for (var i = 0; i < colls.length; i++) {
var from = source + "." + colls[i];
var to = dest + "." + colls[i];
db.adminCommand({renameCollection: from, to: to});
}
```

Be careful  when you  use this command

> renameCollection has different performance implications depending on the target namespace.
>
> If the target database is the same as the source database,
> renameCollection simply changes the namespace. This is a quick
> operation.
>
> If the target database differs from the source database,
> renameCollection copies all documents from the source collection to
> the target collection. Depending on the size of the collection, this
> may take longer to complete.

Comment: what about indexes and other metadata are they maintained or lost?

Comment: @UDB Very likely preserved.  "Renaming a collection" is a _namespace transformation_, essentially your collection named `foo` within the `bar` database has a namespace of `bar.foo`.  The index on `_id` thus has the namespace `bar.foo._id_`.  Renaming the collection (should) perform a prefix search and replace on all namespaces it is aware of, similar to the `--nsFrom` and `--nsTo` [options to `mongorestore`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-nsfrom).

Comment: The cost can be HUGE! https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/#performance If the target database is the same as the source database, renameCollection simply changes the namespace. This is a quick operation.

If the target database differs from the source database, renameCollection copies all documents from the source collection to the target collection. Depending on the size of the collection, this may take longer to complete.

Comment: Please change your answer. Your answer is helpful, because it is possible to move a collection to another database with this command. But it is incorrect, and it can misguide others.

Answer (score 17):

There is no mechanism to re-name databases.  The [currently accepted answer at time of writing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201880/211827) is factually correct and offers some interesting background detail as to the excuse upstream, but offers no suggestions for replicating the behavior.  Other answers point at `copyDatabase`, which is no longer an option as [the functionality has been removed in 4.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-compatibility/#copydb-and-clone-commands).  I've updated [SERVER-701 with my notes](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-701?focusedCommentId=2409300&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-2409300) and incredulity.

Equivalent behavior involves `mongodump` and `mongorestore` in a bit of a dance:

1. Export your data, making note of the "namespaces" in use.  For example, on one of my datasets, I have a collection with the namespace `byzmcbehoomrfjcs9vlj.Analytics` — that prefix (*actually the database name*) will be needed in the next step.
2. Import your data, supplying `--nsFrom` and `--nsTo` arguments.  ([Documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-nsfrom))  Continuing with my above hypothetical (and extremely unreadable) example, to restore to a more sensical name, I invoke:

```
mongorestore --archive=backup.agz --gzip --drop \
    --nsFrom 'byzmcbehoomrfjcs9vlj.*' --nsTo 'rita.*'
```

Some may also point at the `--db` argument to mongorestore, however this, too, is deprecated and triggers a warning against use on non-BSON folder backups with a completely erroneous suggestion to "`use --nsInclude instead`".  The above namespace translation is equivalent to use of the `--db` option, and is the correct namespace manipulation setup to use as we are not attempting to filter what is being restored.

Comment: mongodump with nsFrom/To are the official answer as of 2020

Comment: The documentation part amcgregor linked also has a one-liner example using pipe

`mongodump --archive --db=test | mongorestore --archive  --nsFrom='test.*' --nsTo='examples.*'`

Answer (score 9):

The above process is slow,you can use below method but you need to move collection by collection to another db.

```
use admin
db.runCommand({renameCollection: "[db_old_name].[collection_name]", to: "[db_new_name].[collection_name]"})
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion IMHO. However, it's worth noting that this won't free up the space from the original DB but the rename should be much faster than copying the data.

Comment: Scratch that, it does do a copy anyway (since it doesn't remove the space, it's not really a simple rename) so there's no real advantage to this method over copy and drop.

Answer (score 6):

I tried doing.

```
db.copyDatabase('DB_toBeRenamed','Db_newName','host')
```

and came to know that it has been Deprecated by the mongo community although it created the backup or renamed DB.

```
WARNING: db.copyDatabase is deprecated. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/copydb-clone-deprecation
{
        "note" : "Support for the copydb command has been deprecated. See 
        http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/copydb-clone-deprecation",
        "ok" : 1
}
```

So not convinced with the above approach I had to take Dump of local using below command

```
mongodump --host --db DB_TobeRenamed --out E://FileName/
```

connected to Db.

```
use DB_TobeRenamed
```

then

```
db.dropDatabase()
```

then restored the DB with command.

```
mongorestore -host hostName -d Db_NewName E://FileName/
```

Comment: This is the official approach based on the [deprecation docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#remove-support-for-the-copydb-and-clone-commands).

Answer (score 4):

In the case you put all your data in the admin database (you shouldn't), you'll notice `db.copyDatabase()` won't work because your user requires a lot of privileges you probably don't want to give it. Here is a script to copy the database manually:

```
use old_db
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collName) {
    db[collName].find().forEach(function(d){
        db.getSiblingDB('new_db')[collName].insert(d); 
    }) 
});
```

Comment: `db.copyDatabase` is no longer on mongodb 4.4

Comment: I don't think this will copy indexes

Answer (score 4):

MongoshDeprecatedError: [COMMON-10003] `copyDatabase()` was removed because it was deprecated in MongoDB 4.0

Answer (score 3):

Right, this all seems like a mess, and the other answers don't seem to work for me - presumably because of more changes to the tools - or because I'm using and old version. I hit https://stackoverflow.com/a/63372970/1892584 above until it worked for me

I'm including my answer - if only so I can refer to it next time.

I used this to dump an archive:

`mongodump --archive --db=mongodb+srv://$HOST/$OLD_DB > backup`

and this to restore it into a new db:

`mongorestore  --nsInclude="$OLD_DB.*" --nsFrom='$OLD_DB.*' --nsTo='$NEW_DB.*' mongodb+srv://$HOST/$NEW_DB --archive=backup`

Note the nsInclude, nsFrom and nsTo parameters.

Here is my mongorestore and mongodump version

```
mongodump --version
mongodump version: 100.6.0
git version: 1d46e6e7021f2f5668763dba624e34bb39208cb0
Go version: go1.17.10
   os: darwin
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc

mongorestore --version
mongorestore version: 100.6.0
git version: 1d46e6e7021f2f5668763dba624e34bb39208cb0
Go version: go1.17.10
   os: darwin
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
```

Who knows if this works with different versions.