# Mongodb - Change db name

Tags: mongodb, database

How do i change a db name in mongodb?  Simple question but i can't find anything online on how to do this.  I don't want to have to rebuild my entire database, i just simple want to change the name of it.  thanks.

Comment: Just be careful while renaming you must not mess up with copying the collections to existing database. Checkout my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44986052/1696621

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way is to clone the database to one of a different name

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Copy+Database+Commands

You could go [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-701) and vote for that feature

Answer (score 19):

**Simple use this :**

```
db.copyDatabase("old_db_name","new_db_name","localhost")
use old_db_name
db.dropDatabase();
```

Comment: Just be careful while renaming you must not mess up with copying the collections to existing database. Checkout my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44986052/1696621

Comment: Can be used upto 4.0 version.

Answer (score 4):

Starting in version 4.2, MongoDB removes the deprecated copydb command.
Also, db.copyDatabase() and db.cloneDatabase() can only be run when connected to MongoDB 4.0 or earlier.

Use this approach for version 4.2 as mentioned at [mongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-compatibility/#remove-support-for-the-copydb-and-clone-commands)

> - 1. Use mongodump to dump the test database to an archive mongodump-test-db:

```
mongodump --archive="mongodump-test-db" --db=test
```

> - 2. Use mongorestore with --nsFrom and --nsTo to restore (with database name change) from the archive:

```
mongorestore --archive="mongodump-test-db" --nsFrom='test.*' --nsTo='examples.*'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can dump database

```
./mongodump -d mydb
```

rename folder

```
mv /path/to/dump/folder/mydb /path/to/dump/folder/mynewdb
```

and then restore

```
./mongorestore
```