# Machine hangs when mongoDB db.copyDatabase(...) takes all vailable RAM

Tags: mongodb, database

When I try to copy a database from one mongoDB server to another (About 100GB) the mongo daemon process takes 99% of the available RAM (Windows 64bit 16GB).  As a result the system becomes very slow and sometimes unstable.

Is there any way to avoid it?

MongoDB 2.0.6

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861184/is-there-any-option-to-limit-mongodb-memory-usage

Comment: How are you copying the data?

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN, Means that other applications get stuck and fail to work properly/open/close. Seems like a reasonable lack of memory symptom.

Comment: @daveh, `db.copyDatabase("Table", "Table", host)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Albert.

MongoDB is very much an "in ram" application. Mongo has all of your database memory mapped for usage but normally only the most recently used data will be in RAM (called your working set) and mongo will page out to get any data not in RAM as needed. Normally mongo's behaviour is only to have as much as it needs in RAM, however when you do something like a DB Copy all of the data is needed - thus the mongod consuming all your ram.

There is no ideal solution to this, but if desperately needed you could use WSRM http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732553.aspx to try and limit the amount of RAM consumed by the process. This will have the effect of making the copy take longer and may cause other issues.