# How to rename a database using MongoMapper in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I am trying to rename a database using MongoMapper in ruby.
Is it possible to do the same?
any alternative hack to accomplish the same?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201832/how-do-you-rename-a-mongodb-database

Comment: but is there a way via the mongo ruby driver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the other stack overflow question mentioned above, MongoDB doesn't actually have the ability to rename a database. You can however, copy then delete but be aware this will cause indexes to be rebuilt. You wouldn't want to do this for a large data set.

The mongo-ruby-driver (as well as most 10gen drivers) has the ability to execute any [MongoDB command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/commands/) through a call to the [DB#command](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/DB.html#command-instance_method) method on any DB object instance.

In the Ruby driver you would do the following:

```
require 'mongo'
client = Mongo::MongoClient.new
db = client.db('admin')

db.command({:copydb => 1, :fromdb => oldname, :todb => newname})
client.drop_database(oldname)
```

Update: In newer versions of MongoDB there is a JS shell helper for db.rename() which does exactly what the ruby code above does.

```
function (newName) {
  if(newName == this.getName() || newName.length === 0)
    return;

  this.copyDatabase(this.getName(), newName, "localhost");
  this.dropDatabase();
  db = this.getSiblingDB(newName);
}
```

In addition to that, there is the following feature request ticket for making db.rename() a first class command. Please feel free to upvote this feature.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-701