# How to download production data from MongoHQ in Heroku to local machine?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongohq

I have a web application with production data running on a Cidar stack in Heroku.  The production data is stored in a MongoDB and I use MongoHQ to manage it in production.  I'd like to download the production data to my local machine so I can run my web app locally with production data for debugging purposes.  I'm still relatively new to MongoDB, so after many attempts, I've had no success.

Is there a way to download MongoDB data (collections) from Heroku to a local MongoDB I have on my local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks to this blog post: http://stevespiga.rel.li/mongodump-mongorestore.html

Here a summary of the solution:

1. I ran the command: `heroku config | grep "MONGOHQ"`.  This gave me output of the form:

`MONGOHQ_URL:mongodb://heroku:veryLongPasswordString@somewhere.mongohq.com:88888/app123456`.

2. This can be interpreted as:

`MONGOHQ_URL:mongodb://username:password@host:port/path`

3. Then I dumped the production db to a local directory by running:

`mongodump --db <path> --host <host> --port <port> --username <username> --password <password> --out <folder for dump>`.

4. Example:

`mongodump --db app123456 --host somewhere.mongohq.com --port 88888 --username heroku --password veryLongPasswordString --out ./testDump`.

5. The next step is to take the dumped data and restore it to your local database:

`mongorestore  ./testdump`.

Note, this assumes that you do NOT have a local db of the same name as the dumped db before you restore. If need be you can rename the db by following the steps outlined in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201832/how-do-you-rename-a-mongodb-database).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been trying to figure it for a day.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the MongoHQ dashboard (`$ heroku addons:open mongohq`) there's an option to create a backup and download it from there.

Comment: I've gone to the dashboard as you suggested and after much searching, I still could not location an option to create a backup.  I am using the free version of MongoHQ -- is backup disabled for that version maybe? @rdegges