# Restoring mongodb database with different name

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I've been doing periodic (every 24 hour) backups of my mongodb instance.  This works great, and I can restore them on my staging server with no problem:

```
time mongorestore  --ssl --gzip --authenticationDatabase=admin \
    --host=fra-mongo-staging-1.example.com --port=27017        \
    --username=restore --password=secret --archive="$snapshot_name"
```

But the dbname in production is example_prod, whereas on the staging server I'd like to restore to example_staging.  So I type this:

```
time mongorestore  --ssl --gzip --db "$dbname" --authenticationDatabase=admin \
    --host=fra-mongo-staging-1.example.com --port=27017                       \
    --username=restore --password=secret --archive="$snapshot_name"
```

The only difference is the --db "$dbname" (where $dbname is example_staging).  This doesn't work: I see the lines about preparing, then it says done, but nothing is restored.

```
2019-02-07T11:16:36.743+0000    the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead
2019-02-07T11:16:36.772+0000    archive prelude example_prod.surveys
2019-02-07T11:16:36.773+0000    archive prelude example_prod.settings
2019-02-07T11:16:36.773+0000    archive prelude example_prod.spines
2019-02-07T11:16:36.773+0000    archive prelude example_prod.reduced_authors
2019-02-07T11:16:36.773+0000    archive prelude example_prod.delayed_backend_mongoid_jobs
2019-02-07T11:16:36.773+0000    archive prelude example_prod.email_events
2019-02-07T11:16:36.773+0000    archive prelude example_prod.authors
2019-02-07T11:16:36.774+0000    archive prelude example_prod.crowberry
2019-02-07T11:16:36.774+0000    archive prelude example_prod.bitly
2019-02-07T11:16:36.774+0000    archive prelude example_prod.mytestcollection
2019-02-07T11:16:36.774+0000    archive prelude example_prod.reviews
2019-02-07T11:16:36.774+0000    archive prelude example_prod.books
2019-02-07T11:16:36.774+0000    archive prelude example_prod.candy_events
2019-02-07T11:16:36.774+0000    archive prelude example_prod.features
2019-02-07T11:16:36.774+0000    archive prelude example_prod.elderberry
2019-02-07T11:16:36.776+0000    preparing collections to restore from
2019-02-07T11:17:02.403+0000    done
```

I've also tried using `--tsFrom=example_prod --tsTo=example_staging`, no joy.

Any suggestions on the right way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201832/how-do-you-rename-a-mongodb-database/9201880

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I've also tried using --tsFrom=example_prod --tsTo=example_staging, no joy.

I don't see tsFrom & tsTo in the mongorestore docs -- which version are you using? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/

It looks like there's `nsFrom` and `nsTo` options that take a namespace, so doing `--nsFrom='example_prod.*'` and `--nsTo='example_staging.*'` should work.

From the docs:

> For simple replacements, use asterisks (*) as wild cards. Escape all literal asterisks and backslashes with a backslash. Replacements correspond linearly to matches: each asterisk in --nsFrom must correspond to an asterisk in --nsTo, and the first asterisk in --nsFrom matches the first asterisk in nsTo.

Comment: I'm using version 3.6.5.

Comment: Then you should be using `nsFrom` and `nsTo` rather than `tsFrom` and `tsTo` -- https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/program/mongorestore/

Comment: Yes, it was s/ts/ns/ and the '.*' that I was missing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to dump the database, rename the folder and import it with the new name.

EG,

```
mongodump --out=tempBackup
mv tempBackup/oldDbName tempBackup/newDbName
mongorestore --nsInclude= newDbName tempBackup
```

I didn't try it without --nsInlnclude.