# How do you rename a MongoDB database? (the current status)

Tags: mongodb

I was readind this questions "How do you rename a MongoDB database?" [How do you rename a MongoDB database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201832/how-do-you-rename-a-mongodb-database)

Does anyone know how is the status now. Can we rename the database or still the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/) gives you the option to rename a MonogoDB database by right-clicking the database name and choosing edit:
[image]
[image]
[image]