# Disable and not remove a database or a collection in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver, disable, mongo-collection

All I could find over the internet for this is mostly suggesting

1. [`db.disableFreeMonitoring()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.disableFreeMonitoring/) - which is a admin database monitoring control
2. [`db.collection.remove()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) - but this deletes all the documents (of course based on the filter provided  as well) and
3. [`db.collection.drop()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/#db.collection.drop) - which deletes all the documents and indexes as an optimized approach over removing all.

Is there a way, I can keep the collection or database intact but at the same time **disable** any connection/query to lookup data from it? (I am coming from the point where `disable` and `enable` are commands in HBase actually.)

Comment: [Is it possible to detach some specific database from MongoDB Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266468/is-it-possible-to-detach-some-specific-database-from-mongodb-server).

Comment: I don't think a collection can be disabled, but you might use [renameCollection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/index.html#renamecollection) to obfuscate it.

Comment: @prasad_ RAM consumption is not my primary concern, access control is..practically - I want to delete, but before that disable to see if **any** of my underlying service might get impacted. In which case I could just enable back. I understand drop with backup and restore is a workaround, but both time and disk(movement) consuming.

Comment: @Joe Interesting suggestion indeed. Should be quick to rename a database.. but then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201832/how-do-you-rename-a-mongodb-database !! :|

Comment: @Joe I would suggest you make an answer to this. For now, all I could do with was perform a `getCollections` and iterate over each to rename them all.