# mongorestore 0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

Im trying to migrate mongo, from local to atlas. I did mongodump, it creted .z archive properly.

However when i try to restore like below :

```
mongorestore --uri="mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@xxxxx.ipmg6.mongodb.net/myDbName" --archive=mongodump_2021-05-22_09-05-44.gz --gzip
```

I see output

```
2021-05-23T07:25:01.340+0200    The --db and --collection flags are deprecated for this use-case; please use --nsInclude instead, i.e. with --nsInclude=${DATABASE}.${COLLECTION}
2021-05-23T07:25:01.350+0200    preparing collections to restore from
2021-05-23T07:25:01.360+0200    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

No error but also no documents processed. Any idea what is wrong? And i something there is no error or warning from mongo?

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: the .gz file is 29KB.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok solution is that `--nsInclude` was missing. If one want to restore whole db then `--nsInclude="*"` should be used.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
mongorestore --drop /dump --nsInclude="*"
```

The "/dump" bit is the path to the mongodump directory.